# invoking `\placelistofpublications` several times in a document

Tags: bibliographies, context

I want to give my lectures conclusion to students with a bibliography. For the sake of saving paper, I'd like to have two (or more) pieces of such text on a single page. Unfortunately, the second call for `\placelistofpublications` has no output, as shown in this MWE (manuals is shipped with a lmtx install, I hope the manuals database is also available with TeXlive):

```
\usebtxdataset [manuals]

\starttext

\nocite[h2o:layouts-in-context]
\nocite[h2o:fonts-in-context]
\nocite[h2o:metafun-manual]

\dorecurse{2}{
   \input ward

   \placelistofpublications 
}

\stoptext
```

[image: compilation output: only one bibliography list, two were expected]

Is there any way to overcome this? Trying with buffers was of little help.
I understand that usually no one wants to output a bibliography twice, so it might be a corner case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When going through the bibliographies manual (https://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf), I noticed that `\placelistofpublications` inherits from `\setupbtxrendering` and the latter has an option for `repeat=yes`. Seems like this results in something along the lines of what the question is looking for:

```
\usebtxdataset [manuals]

\starttext

\dorecurse{2}{
   \input ward

   \placelistofpublications[repeat=yes, method=dataset] 
}

\stoptext
```

The issue however, is that actually using `\nocite` seems to cause weird lua errors about comparing numbers with strings. `\cite` seems to work fine though so hopefully the use of `\nocite` is not a strict requirement (or can be replaced with the `method=dataset` approach).